# Are values returned by .NET Environment class secure to use for authorization

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

Can I be sure that values returned by [Environment class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx) (especially UserName and UserDomainName) are valid? Is there any way that user can inject own values to be returned by those properties? It is important for me, because I want to use this values for authorization.

Comment: Well they can just set them in a command prompt and then run the program...

Comment: Ah, it doesn't actually check the environment variables, I think they named the class that because it returns data about the conceptual environment the program is running in.

Comment: Depends on the context.  If this code is running on the user's own machines, in their own security context, they can manipulate the values however they want - but then again they don't need to, since whatever the code is going to do if the username matches, they could just do directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft claims [it should be secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> You can use the UserName property to identify the user on the current thread, to the system and application for security or access purposes. It can also be used to customize a particular application for each user.
>
> The UserName property wraps a call to the Windows GetUserName function. The domain account credentials for a user are formatted as the user's domain name, the '\' character, and user name. Use the UserDomainName property to obtain the user's domain name and the UserName property to obtain the user name.

But I suppose, in the presence of a hostile attacker with unlimited time and money, they can build their own version of Windows that returns whatever they want here, or use a driver to patch GetUserName, etc.  Ultimately you would need to use something like [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) if you have no trust in the clients.

Comment: Or an attacker could simply run the code on their own machine where they have set the username and the domain to match the one being checked for.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Windows won't let you directly set the username and password except by patching the OS somehow, but either way Kerberos will prevent that sort of attack.

Comment: Sure it will. As an attacker, if I want to spoof the domain "megacorpone" with the username "foobar", I install Windows on my own machine, install Windows Server on another machine as a PDC of the "megacorpone" domain and setup a user called "foobar". I simply log in as "foobar" on the workstation and then the `UserName` property will be populated in the application.

Comment: @SilverlightFox sure, or I could attach a debugger and change the strings as they're returned, or rewrite packets as they go out on the network.  If an attacker can touch the client machine or is an admin, there are a million ways if they have the time and care to.  If I'm a normal user on a box I can't touch, I can't call SetUserName("megacorphone\foobar").

Comment: Of course. My point was that they would not need to "build their own version of Windows" when they could do something much less elaborate with a couple of VMs - I was simply suggesting an easier exploitation method if the OP considered that the risk an attacker would build their own Windows as too low. I was building on your point by making the threat a little more realistic.